# Colouring Bounded Area Under Curve Matlab

Tags: matlab, area

I was wondering if anyone knew how I could colour the area under the curve for the below code. I have tried to use `area(Mu)`, however this returns a shaded area slightly different to the plot.

```
n=1;
a=[0:0.001:4];
A=(a.*n);
B=(n-n.*a);
C=(1-n);
Mu=(-B+sqrt((B.^2)-(4.*A.*C)))./(2.*A);
plot(a,Mu)
xlim([0 4])
ylim([0 .8])
```

Comment: It's straight-forward... Just replace `plot` with `area` which gives you the line `area(a,Mu)`. This can be found in the [documentation](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/area.html) like this: «*`area(X,Y)` For vectors `X` and `Y`, `area(X,Y)` is the same as `plot(X,Y)` except that the area between `0` and `Y` is filled.*»

Comment: @Matt removing the `plot` call is not the correct generic answer if the user wants to do something "special" with the boundary. The OP has tried `area`, so it's not like she's unaware that the function exists...

Comment: @excaza Of course, if the OP needs the `plot`, she needs to call `area` after `hold on` or first plot the area and then the line. She tried `area(Mu)` but not `area(a,Mu)`... That's the reason why used the word *replace* to emphasize that the arguments are exactly the same. The citation corresponds to that as well.

Comment: @Matt telling them to remove functions from their code unrelated to the asked question, and therefore *harming* their function, is not as helpful as explaining to them why what they already tried didn't work as they expected.

Comment: @excaza I do not agree that it *harms* the function because I assume the OP knows how to draw the line again if needed. The only thing I wanted to express with my first comment is basically to use the same arguments for `area` as for `plot`. I agree that I could have explained *why* it caused the wrong result. Namely because the x-axis does not match. BTW: I agree as well to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448453/colouring-bounded-area-under-curve-matlab?noredirect=1#comment60518601_36448818) comment.

Answer (score 4):

You're almost there. `area(Mu)` uses a default value such that it, in this case, actually executes `area([1:length(Mu)],Mu)`. This gives you the undesired result, whilst `area(a,Mu)` is the same as `plot(a,Mu)` except that the area between 0 and Mu is filled.

Use `area(a,Mu)`. Then plot your line on top of the area, or just change the edge of the area. See example below:

```
n=1;
a=[0:0.001:4];
A=(a.*n);
B=(n-n.*a);
C=(1-n);
Mu=(-B+sqrt((B.^2)-(4.*A.*C)))./(2.*A);
area(a,Mu)
hold on
xlim([0 4])
ylim([0 .8])
plot(a,Mu)
```

Comment: I just realized that this is almost exactly what you tried :P Anyway, this should work and it's good to have the answer posted if other users are looking at the same problem in the future. Please 'accept' the answer and upvote if this was what you were looking for. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: hmmm, might want to add a `hold on` in there?

Comment: If you want this answer to be helpful to other users I suggest you explain how your code differs and *why* you made the changes rather than copy+pasting a block of code without context.

Comment: @GameOfThrows: There is an edge on area, so in fact, we could skip the plot command I believe. However, I see your point. I will edit.

Comment: @excaza: Including the original code, in this case, is useful in the answer as the answer becomes immediately applicable. You can copy paste the code in matlab and it will work. However, I agree that it is not clear enough. I will make an edit. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: You have still not explained what the difference is between `area(Mu)` and `area(a, Mu)`. "It will work" is not at all useful.

Comment: I'd say that `help area` could be left for the user to try. However I am all for thorough explanations. Although, saying that it's "...not at all useful" seems exaggerated and unnecessary. I hope you approve my edit, please feel free to comment with any ideas for improvement. I'd be happy to edit for the benefit of other users.

Comment: It is not exaggerated. People need to *understand* what they are doing, not blindly copy+paste code just because it works in one case.